# Flutter: How can i execute the method on specific time and date using alarm manager plugin in flutter?

Tags: plugins, background, dart, flutter, alarmmanager

I am trying to run method(Send Email Method) on specific date and time, even the app is closed using alarm manager plugin in flutter. I am using date and time picker to define the date.

I am not able to figure it out how to do that.

I had tried some example given in repo. Like i was trying to show toast in every minute. But when app is closed toast is not appearing.

I expected it will show the toast even the application is closed.

Comment: Any update about it?

Comment: You can use alarm manager.